# Test Explorer not discovering Xunit tests [VS 15]

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, visual-studio-2015, xunit, test-explorer

I am currently running VS 2015 Enterprise edition. My `global.json` file is as follows:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src"],
  "sdk": {
    "architecture": "x86",
    "runtime": "coreclr",
    "version": "1.0.0-beta6"
  }
}
```

My test project file uses the following references:

```
    "xunit": "2.1.0-beta4-*",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta4-*"
  },
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx -xml testresults.xml"
  },
```

Test Explorer does not discover my test files.  I am also using Resharper v9.2. It does discover my test files; however, I get an inconclusive message and a message that reads:

> Unable to run xUnit.net tests - File not found: {solution path}\artifacts\bin\{Project Name}\{Project Name}.dll.

One additional thing.  I am frequently getting a dnx.exe crash when I build my test project.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

One more thing:  I can successfully run the tests from the command prompt / PowerShell using the command `dnx . test`.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue using current beta8 and xunit.dnx using the currently released extension.

Answer (score 1):

This was posted before DNX beta8 was released but maybe you used early builds of beta8 or even beta7? I had the same problem with DNX beta8 and it was because the xunit dependencies needed to be updated aswell. You have xunit "2.1.0-beta4-*" but if you change it to "2.1.0-*" you will get newer versions with support for DNX beta8.

From:

```
"dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0-beta4-*",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-beta4-*",
```

To:

```
"dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0-*",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-*",
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Was this for the ReSharper xUnit runner, or the built-in Visual Studio "Test Explorer"? I tried several dependency versions and though I can get them to work fine in VS Test Explorer, the R# xUnit runner still complains about not finding the assemblies (they get generated in a different location).

Comment: This was for the built-in Visual Studio "Test Explorer", so I'm not sure of the R# xUnit runner.